# Token based authentication in Sharepoint 2016

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-server, oauth

Hi I want to obtain **Bearer token** in Sharepoint 2016 on premise environment for the following code.

> GET https://{site_url}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Title')
> Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
> Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"

How do I achieve it using postman.

Answer (score 1):

To access SharePoint 2016 Rest API through Postman, below are the steps:

Step 1 – Get your SharePoint site’s FormDigest using Contextinfo call

1. In Postman, the contextinfo endpoint URL for your SharePoint Site…something like:   https://mySharePointSite/_api/contextinfo
2. Authothorization type choose NTLM Authothorization.
3. Set the Accept header: application/json;odata=verbose
4. Choose post method.

[image]

With Results:
1.Copy the big string of characters inside FormDigestValue

[image]

Step 2 – Make your HTML GET Request (or POST if you’re posting)

1. Enter your endpoint URL…something like:  https://mySharePointSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(‘MyListName’)/items?$select=Title
2. Set the Accept header:  application/json;odata=verbose
3. Add the header X-RequestDigest and paste the FormDigestValue copied above into it

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want to make a request using a Bearer token using Authorization as Bearer not NTLM. Please guide me with that.